# Parse digits in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, makefile, gnu-make

I want to parse digits of a version in a Makefile.
I am getting the version in a variable, that variable reads VER=10.11.12-0.1.2

Now I want each individual digits in different variables let's say A=10, B=11 and so on..
I have tried combinations of sed and awk but not getting it work exactly I want.. also it seems piped output doesn't work in Makefile.

`A=$(shell echo ${VER} | awk -F . "{print $1}")`

Any inputs?

Comment: "seems piped output doesn't work in Makefile" -- that's not universally true; it depends on _exactly_ how you do it. If you showed us a [mre], we could tell you exactly what went wrong and how to avoid it.

Comment: Well the first thing to remember is that `$` is special to make: it introduces a variable.  If you want to pass a `$` to the shell that you're invoking, you need to escape it as `$$`.  So try `A := $(shell ... '{print $$1}')`.  Of course you also want to use single-quotes not double quotes, to escape the `$` from the shell, because you want to pass it to `awk`.

Comment: The way to write shell commands in make is FIRST, make it work correctly at the shell prompt.  Then after you have that working, copy/paste the command into a `$(shell ...)` function, replacing all instances of `$` in the shell script with `$$` and substituting any make variables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it with Gnu make:

```
VER = 10.11.12-0.1.2
VERNUMS := $(subst ., ,$(subst -, ,$(VER)))
A = $(word 1,$(VERNUMS))
B = $(word 2,$(VERNUMS))
# Etc.
```

Comment: Why backslashes? They are (almost) not special for make, so your variables `A` and `B` will have trailing backslashes, probably not what you want.

Comment: @renaud: ok, i changed it but i haven't tested it.